# Как десериализовать дату из <input type="date" .../> для ее отправки через форму?

Tags: javascript, java, html

```
<form action = "../my" method="post">
    <input type="date" name="date"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Сервер:

```
@RequestMapping(value="my", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void my(@RequestParam("date") Date date) {
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

Ошибка с `<input type="date" name="date"/>`:

> The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Ошибка без `<input type="date" name="date"/>`:

> Required Date parameter 'date' is not present

То есть дата неправильно сериализуется.

Comment: для отправки даты нет подходящего контент тайпа. поэтому сериализуйте и десериализуйте там, где используете

Comment: @Yugofx а как заставить форму отправлять при нажатии на submit не дату, а строку?

Comment: @Miron не совсем вас понял, это итак строка

Comment: @Yugofx Вы оказались правы. Я изменил Date на String, и все заработало. Оставьте ответ - приму